# Java Swing: How to prevent system copy,cut,paste action?

Tags: java, swing, keylistener

So I am trying to prevent the user from being able to use the default system actions by pressing control + C, control + X, control + V.

I want anywhere inside this particular scrollPane, to catch the key. The scrollPane loads a Component into itself, for example JLabel.

```
scrollPane.addKeyListener(new KeyListener(){
    @Override
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent evt) {
        if (evt.isControlDown() && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_C) {
                System.out.println("disabled");
        } else if (evt.isControlDown() && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_X) {
               System.out.println("disabled");
        } else if (evt.isControlDown() && evt.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.VK_V) {
               System.out.println("disabled");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }

    @Override
    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent arg0) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    }
});
```

However, nothing is being printed.

I added the same keylistener to a Jtree but it's working for that.

**UPDATE:**

So using keybinds, how do I get a JoptionPane to appear?

```
  scrollPane.getInputMap(JComponent.WHEN_FOCUSED)
                        .put(KeyStroke.getKeyStroke(KeyEvent.VK_C, KeyEvent.CTRL_DOWN_MASK), 
                                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "disabled"));
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

better would be implements [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html) rather than [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), because

1) `KeyListener` works only when `JComponent` has `Focus` in the Window,

2)  you set `KeyListener` to `JScrollPane` instead of `JTree`

3) for KeyBindings you can set InputMap and ActionMap for

- to the TopLevel Container (`JFrame, JDialog, JWindow`)
- concrete `JComponent`(s)

4) for `KeyListener` and `KeyBindings` this TopLevel Container must have Focus on the Screen

5) then you can set for required `event(s)#consume()`;

Comment: how do I add an action for the ActionMap?

Comment: @Kim Jong Woo for example here - http://stackoverflow.com/a/7977155/714968 , or here http://stackoverflow.com/a/7940227/714968

Comment: I did not know about KeyBindings at all. Thank you +1

Answer (score 5):

You should attach your custom TransferHandler that will override `getCutAction` and `getCopyAction` to your all instances of JComponent you want to prevent from user's copy/paste.

Please take a look here for details: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.5.0/docs/guide/swing/1.4/dnd.html#ClipboardTransferSupport

Answer (score 3):

Use KeyBindings
http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html