# Is it possible to "intercept" a copy/cut/paste action and replace it with my own code?

Tags: java, javafx-8

I am writing an application where I want to intercept copy/cut/paste actions and "replace" them with my own code - for example I want to be notified on a copy action and catch it, and I want to "replace" the paste-action-handling code with my own code so I can change the behaviour of what happens if the user tries to paste something in e.g. an input field.

A nice bonus would be if I can add copy- and paste-actions to fields like a choice box.

Is this possible without digging into deeply internal JavaFX code?

Comment: Have you read the JavaFX documentation?  What did it say?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can implement listeners for the short cut keys on the controls that you need to specify the copy/paste behavior.  You need to listen for keystrokes of:

```
KeyEvent.VK_C
KeyEvent.VK_V
KeyEvent.VK_X
```

Each of these needs to be combined with the meta or control key mask.  Then you just need to handle the [clipboard](http://docs.oracle.com/javafx/2/api/javafx/scene/input/Clipboard.html).

Alternatively, you should see this question that addresses a similar issue, but the solution uses keybindings:
[Java Swing: How to prevent system copy,cut,paste action?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8323611/java-swing-how-to-prevent-system-copy-cut-paste-action?rq=1)

Comment: Thanks for answering!

Will this offer the "native" copy/paste/cut behaviour for all OSes or will I have to listen to something different on e.g. OS X?

Comment: I solved it with KeyEvent#isShortcutDown and KeyCode.C, KeyCode.V and KeyCode.X respectively now.

Comment: Note that Ctrl+Ins, Shift+Del, and Shift+Ins are also shortcuts for copying, cutting, and pasting.

Comment: KeyEvent.VK_C is awt, not javafx