# JApplet - alphabet will not allowed

Tags: java, swing, validation, japplet

this is my code, which is written inside my applet

```
KeyListener keyListener = new KeyListener() 
{
    public void keyPressed(KeyEvent keyEvent) 
    {
        validate valid=new validate();
        valid.errorMessage(txt_district_id, keyEvent);
    }

    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent keyEvent) 
    {       
    }

    public void keyTyped(KeyEvent keyEvent) 
    {       
    }

};
txt_district_id.addKeyListener(keyListener);
```

and code of **validate class** is

```
public class validate
{
    public String errorMessage(KeyEvent keyEvent,JTextField txt)
    {
        int keyCode = keyEvent.getKeyCode();
        String keyText = KeyEvent.getKeyText(keyCode);
        //msg.setText(title + " : " + keyText + " / " + keyEvent.getKeyChar());
        if(keyCode > 47 && keyCode < 58)
        {
            txt.setEditable(true);
        }
        else
        {
            txt.setEditable(false);
            return "Only Numeric Value Accepted";
        }
    }
}
```

everything working properly, but the problem is whenever user input any alphabet the textfield will become disable, and that is my problem. I mean it should like, alphabet can not be entered and textfield should be enabled in any case. Thanks in advance.!!

Comment: 1) Please use a consistent and logical indent for code blocks.  2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Answer (score 2):

1. Use [DocumentListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/documentlistener.html) for listening changes inside [JTextComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/text.html),
2. Don't use [KeyListener](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/events/keylistener.html), this `Listener` is designated for prehistoric AWT Components, for [Swing JComponents](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/index.html) ([JApplet](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/deployment/applet/index.html)) use [KeyBindings](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/keybinding.html)

Comment: example for the KeyBindings, which i can refer for my problem. to check whether input is alphabet or not.

Comment: use DocumentListener, and you have to forgot thinking about KeyBindings for JTextComponents

Comment: i found the help for KeyBindings, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7976209/using-keybinding-to-get-keycode, but i don't think so, it will solve my problem.